# Align equation to left in nested list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, enumerate

I want the equation to align left in this specific scenario(i.e. a nested enumerate) and dont want to change the environment setting for the whole article. How do i proceed?
Below is my code and preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float} %% keep tables and figures in float position
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

...

```
\item Find the unique cubic polynomial P that satisfies 
    \begin{equation*}
        P(-2) = 1, P(-1) = 4 P(0) = 2, P(2) = 4.
    \end{equation*}
    Write P in both the Lagrange and Newton forms 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lagrange: $construct l_j for j \in  [1,4]$ \par
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{aligned}
                l_1(x) = \frac{1}{-8}(x+1)x(x-2) \\
                l_2(x) = \frac{1}{3}(x+2)x(x-2) \\
                l_3(x) = \frac{1}{-4}(x+2)(x+1)(x-2) \\
                l_4(x) = \frac{1}{24}(x+2)(x+1)x \\
                P(x) = l_1(x)+4l_2(x)+2l_3(x)+4l_4(x)    
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
        \item Newton
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have to specify the alignment point with an ampersand. If you don't, the equations will be aligned at the end of line, i.e. right-aligned. This being sais=d, what you want is not very clear. Do you want the equations to be aligned at the left margin of the enumeration  perhaps (i.e.  under the L of Lagrange)?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you wish to align the 5 equations in the `aligned` environment on their respective `=` ("is equal to") symbols. The `&` ("ampersand") symbol should be used to indicate the desired alignment points. (As you've discovered, if no alignment points are specified, the equations end up being right-aligned.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Find the unique cubic polynomial $P$ that satisfies 
    \begin{equation*}
        P(-2)=1,\quad P(-1)=4,\quad P(0)=2,\quad P(2)=4\,.
    \end{equation*}
\item Write $P$ in both the Lagrange and Newton forms.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Lagrange: Construct $l_j$ for $j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ 
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{aligned}
                l_1(x) &= -\frac{1}{8}(x+1)x(x-2) \\
                l_2(x) &= \frac{1}{3}(x+2)x(x-2) \\
                l_3(x) &= -\frac{1}{4}(x+2)(x+1)(x-2) \\
                l_4(x) &= \frac{1}{24}(x+2)(x+1)x \\
                P(x)   &= l_1(x) +4l_2(x) +2l_3(x) +4l_4(x)    
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
        \item Newton: \dots
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```